# How to work on selectedRowChange event with kendo-grid-checkbox-column in angular 6

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular6, kendo-grid

I am currently working on the scenario where i want to select the rows by using the `kendo-grid-checkbox-column` and we have also implemented the functionality of `selectionChange`.

I have to implement the `kendo-grid-checkbox-column` to select the particular rows for some action. For that i have used the following code:

```
<kendo-grid-checkbox-column showSelectAll="true"></kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
```

but whenever i tick the checkbox in any row the `selectionChange` event fires. Following is the code :

```
public selectedRowChange(selectionEvent: SelectionEvent) {
}
```

Is there any solution to stop triggering `selectionChange` event when i click on the checkbox?